# Jtable refresh with new data

Tags: swing, jtable, jcheckbox

1. I  have load button which loads the data into jtable
2. **I am able to load new data to jtable**.
3. ***but when I reload the data and click jcheckbox, the old data comes up.***
   I am using defaulttablemodel option.
   pls run the prog and help me where i have gone wrong.

   ```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.EventQueue;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JComponent;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
   import javax.swing.JTable;
   import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

   public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
   JTable table;
   private static final int CHECK_COL = 3;
       String[] columnNames = {
       "Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};
       Object[][] data = {
       {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, false},
       {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, false},
       {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, false},
       {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, false},
       {"France", "Paris", 60, false},
       {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, false},
       {"India", "New Deli", 1046, false}
       };
       DefaultTableModel dtm ;
       // static JScrollPane scrollpane= new JScrollPane();
       public MainWindow() {
       setTitle("Marking of data");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("load");
       button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if(dtm!=null){
               System .out .println("NOT EMPTY");
               int c = dtm.getRowCount();
           // for (int i=c-1; i>=0; i--)
           // {
               // dtm.removeRow(i);
               // table.revalidate();
           // }
               loadtable();
                }
           if(dtm==null){
               System .out .println("EMPTY");
               loadtable();
           }
         }
         });

         JButton button = new JButton("check");
         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
               Boolean b = ((Boolean) table.getValueAt(row, CHECK_COL));
               if (b.booleanValue()) {
                   System.out.print("row " + row + " is " + b + ": ");
                   for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                       System.out.print(table.getValueAt(row, col) + " ");
                   }
                   System.out.println();
               }
           }
         }
         });
         JPanel buttonpanel1 = new JPanel();
         buttonpanel1.add(button1);
         JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
         buttonpanel.add(button);
         add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         add(buttonpanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         pack();
         setLocationByPlatform(true);
         setVisible(true);
         }
         public void loadtable(){
       dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
           @Override
           public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
               return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
           }
           @Override
           public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
               return (colIndex == CHECK_COL);
           }
         };
         table = new JTable(dtm);
         JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
         add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         pack();
         setVisible(true);
         }


        public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           new MainWindow();
         }
        });
        }
         }
   ```

help needed. pls

Answer (score 0):

The default table model copies the data from the two-dimensional array into its own vectors.

Each time you press the load button, you create a new default table model using the same data, and a new copy is made to the new table model's vectors.

Your code resets the table model each time the load button is pressed, so of course, the old data comes up.